# Meaning of the code below

Tags: php

I just wanted to ask what this code means? I know that this code connects to the database and its meant to show  `$error[count($error)]` and its in an array. But for some reason the errors wont show up

```
function query($iquery, &$error)
    {
        $connection = get_connection($error);
        if ($connection) {
            $result =  mysql_query($iquery, $connection);
            if (!$result)
                $error[count($error)] = "Query '$iquery' failed" + mysql_error();
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

especially what this line means:

```
$error[count($error)] = "Query '$iquery' failed" + mysql_error();
```

Comment: `$error[count($error)]` adds an element to the end of an array.  You could also do `$error[] = '';` or `array_push($error, '');` instead.

Comment: "Meaning" is all about context. You can certainly look up each function in the [PHP manual](www.php.net/manual/) to gain an understanding of what the snippet does, but meaning can only be understood by knowing what surrounds and uses this code.

Comment: What do you think? it gets a database connection (assuming from `get_connection(..)`) and performs a query and returns results. In case of errors, it updates a variable that has been passed by reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function declaration, it accepts a variable to hold a query called `$iquery` and 
it passes BY REFERENCE, an error containing variable called `$error`

```
    function query($iquery, &$error)
        {
```

This makes a connection to a database, and stores the connection in a variable called `$connection`

```
        $connection = get_connection($error);
```

This checks to see if the connection was successful, and if so, runs the code within

```
        if ($connection) {
```

This captures the result of the query once it has been run

**NOTE** This function `mysql_query()` should no longer be used.

```
            $result =  mysql_query($iquery, $connection);
```

This portion checks to see if the query completed successfully and if not, it adds an error to the array `$error` which has been passed by reference, so it will update the original array that has been passed to the function `query($iquery, &$error)` with the MySQL generated error.

```
            if (!$result)
                $error[count($error)] = "Query '$iquery' failed" + mysql_error();
        }
```

The function then returns what it received from the query, which would be NULL in the case of a query error.

```
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

because of the `&$`, the error array is being passed by reference. the line you ask about:

```
$error[count($error)] = "Query '$iquery' failed" + mysql_error();
```

... is then updating that array with data than can be accessed from after where `query()` was called

Answer (score 1):

It just attempts to run a query and returns the query resource. If there's an error, it adds it to an array.